# Java's CORBA ORB and connecting to a 3rd party Naming Service

Tags: java, corba, interop, nameservice

The Following is from [JavaTM IDL FAQ](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/idl/jidlFAQ.html):

> **How do I connect to a 3rd-party Naming Service from Sun's ORB?**
>
> ***The recommended way*** is to use the

[Interoperable Naming Service (INS)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/idl/INStutorial.html)

> , ***if this option is supported by
>   the 3rd-party Naming Service***.
>
> To use the Sun ORB with another
>   vendor's Naming Service,
>
> - Start the 3rd-party name server on Host and Port.
> - Pass the following argument to ORB.init():
>
>   ```
>   -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc:iiop:1.2@:/NameService
>   ```
>
>   When you do orb.resolve_initial_references(
>     "NameService" ), you should be able to
>     connect to 3rd-party Name Service. If
>     you are still not able to connect, try
>     these troubleshooting hints:
> - Verify that the 3rd-party Name Service supports INS.
> - Verify that the host and port information is accurate.
> - Verify that the 3rd-party Name Service has been started successfully.
> - Verify that the 3rd-party Name Service supports GIOP 1.2. If not,
>     refer to the Name Server's
>     documentation for the correct the GIOP
>     version, and modify the corbaloc: URL
>     accordingly.
> - Determine if the 3rd-party Name Service has a different object key it
>     uses to contact NameService. If so,
>     refer to the Name Server's
>     documentation.

**I am new to CORBA** and I would like to know whether or not there is another way to connect to a 3rd party Naming Service which might not be so "recommended". After all how am I to guess if, as yet unknown, 3rd party naming service supports INS (Interoperable Naming Service). But then again, I did mention that I am new to these things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been more than 10 happy years since CORBA was last inflicted on me, but I still remember a few things.

The "not recommended" way is to use a IOR (Interoperable Naming Reference), which is CORBA's equivalent of a URL. The IOR is essentially a string representation of the location of a live CORBA object. A client can convert the IOR into a handle on that object.

Normally, the IOR itself points to a CoS Naming Service, which is a registry of other objects, but it's lust as valid to have an IOR that points directly at a remote object.

See this [ancient article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-1999/jw-02-enterprise.html) (from 1999, the last time anyone cared about CORBA) to see how to deal with IORs.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-1999/jw-02-enterprise.html?page=4 is where I found the answer I had been looking for, thanks!